# MySQL BEFORE DELETE trigger with double join and condition

Tags: mysql, triggers

**Hello, colleagues.**

I have kind of an issue trying to implement a **before delete trigger** with multiple joins and condition.

I have table of users, table of groups and a connection table to make it many to many.

The sense of trigger is to allow deletion for groups without students and to disallow the others.

The code I have for now is that:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER
  groups_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  DECLARE students int;

  SET students = (SELECT
    count(title)
  FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN student_to_group stg ON (u.id = stg.student_id)
    INNER JOIN groups g ON (stg.group_id = g.id)
  GROUP BY
    group_id
  HAVING
    group_id = OLD.id);

  IF students = 0 THEN DELETE FROM groups where id = OLD.id;
  END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

It passed the syntax checking but does not work. Are there any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better define a foreign key with `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Yes, I know about that way. Foreign keys is the other way, the question is how to do that with triggers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use a better solution with a foreign key and `ON DELETE RESTRICT`.

However - To stop a deletion with a trigger, you need to raise an error when any student is related with the group. And there is no need for any joins. The only table you need to read from is `student_to_group`. You also don't need to count all students in the group. You just need to know if any student is connected with this group, which is best done with `EXISTS`.

To raise an error you can use the [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) command.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER
  groups_before_delete BEFORE DELETE ON groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student_to_group stg WHERE stg.group_id = OLD.id) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot delete a group which has students';
    END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. Very nice optimized decision.